# How to delete hidden/closed multiple webparts programmatically that falls under a site in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

My requirement is to delete hidden/unused webparts under a site.
Also am not able to get list of all pages under a site.
Need Help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folks, find partially code for above question

- Create object of site and web.

> using (SPSite oSite = new>SPSite(cbWebSite.SelectedItem.ToString()))
>    using (SPWeb web = oSite.OpenWeb())

- Create a datatable to store list of stale,closed/hidden webparts.

> dtWebParts =
>   (System.Data.DataTable)CreateDataTableForUnusedWebParts();
>
> ```
>  System.Data.DataTable dtWebPartReport = new
>   System.Data.DataTable();
>
>         DataColumn dtCol = new DataColumn();
>         dtCol.ColumnName = COLUMN_WEBAPP_NAME;
>         dtCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
>         dtWebPartReport.Columns.Add(dtCol);
>         .
>         .
>         .
> ```

- Call the function to generate report.

  ```
      private void generateWebPartReportForWeb(SPWeb oWeb, SPSite oSite)
  {
  ```

> ```
>         try
>         {
>             //If team Site then read homepage
>             foreach (SPFile rootFile in oWeb.Files)
>             {
>                 checkPageForWebParts(oWeb, oSite,rootFile);
>             }
>
>             foreach (SPList oList in oWeb.Lists)
>             {
>                 if (oList.BaseType == SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary)
>                 {
>                     lstName = oList.Title.ToString();
>                     spDocumentLibrary =(SPDocumentLibrary)oWeb.Lists[lstName];
>                     if (spDocumentLibrary.Title.ToString() !="Master Page Gallery" &&
>                         spDocumentLibrary.Title.ToString() !="dataconnectionLib" &&
>                         spDocumentLibrary.Title.ToString() !="Form Templates" &&
>                         spDocumentLibrary.Title.ToString() !="Images" &&
>                         spDocumentLibrary.Title.ToString() !="List Template Gallery" &
>                         spDocumentLibrary.Title.ToString() !="Scripts" &&
>                         spDocumentLibrary.Title.ToString() !="Site Template Gallery" &
>                         spDocumentLibrary.Title.ToString() !="Style Library" &&
>                         spDocumentLibrary.Title.ToString() !="Web Part Gallery" &&
>                         spDocumentLibrary.Title.ToString() !="Workflows")
>                     {
>
>                         foreach (SPListItem spListItem in spDocumentLibrary.Items)
>                         {
>                             spFile = spListItem.File;
>                             checkPageForWebParts(oWeb, oSite,spFile);
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>
>             if (oWeb.Webs.Count > 0)
>             {
>                 foreach (SPWeb subsite in oWeb.Webs)
>                 {
>                     generateWebPartReportForWeb(subsite, oSite);
>                 }
>             }
>
>             DataView dv = dtWebParts.DefaultView;
>             dv.Sort = "Document Library Path  ASC";
>             dataGridView1.DataSource = dtWebParts;
>             dataGridView1.Update();
>
>         }
> ```

- Code to Check for webpart in PAGES :

> ```
>            private void checkPageForWebParts(SPWeb oWeb,SPSite oSite, SPFile spFile)
>          {
>             try
>              {
>             string[] strFileName = spFile.Name.Split('.');
>             string fileExtension = strFileName[strFileName.Length - 1].ToUpper();
>             if (fileExtension.ToUpper() == "ASPX")
>             {
>                 using (SPLimitedWebPartManager wpm = oWeb.GetLimitedWebPartManager(spFile.Url, PersonalizationScope.Shared))
>                 {
>                     foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart wp in wpm.WebParts)
>                     {
>                         if (wp.IsClosed || wp.Hidden)
>                         {
>                             DataRow dr = dtWebParts.NewRow();
>                             if (oSite.WebApplication.Name != null)
>                                 dr[COLUMN_WEBAPP_NAME] = oSite.WebApplication.Name;
>                             if (oSite.Url != null)
>                                 dr[COLUMN_SITECOLLECTION_NAME] = oSite.Url;
>                             if (oWeb.Name != null)
>                                 dr[COLUMN_SUBSITE_NAME] = oWeb.Name;
>                             if (oWeb.Url != null)
>                                 dr[COLUMN_DOCLIB_PATH] =cbWebApp.SelectedItem.ToString() + spFile.ServerRelativeUrl;//oWeb.Url + "/" + spDocumentLibrary.ToString();
>                             if (spFile.Name != null)
>                                 dr[COLUMN_DOCNAME] = spFile.Name;
>                             if (wp.Title != null)
>                                 dr["WebPart Name"] = wp.Title;
>                             if (wp.IsClosed)
>                                 dr["Hidden/Closed"] = "Closed";
>                             else if (wp.Hidden)
>                                 dr["Hidden/Closed"] = "Hidden";
>
>                             dtWebParts.Rows.Add(dr);
>                             dtWebParts.AcceptChanges();
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2007/01/18/how-to-get-a-list-of-web-parts-on-a-page.aspx) will be helpful to you.

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
      list = new BulletedList();
      WebPartZoneCollection zones = this.WebPartManager.Zones;
      foreach (WebPartZone zone in zones)
      {
        WebPartCollection webparts = zone.WebParts;
        foreach (WebPart webpart in webparts)
        {
          **You can check webpart.hidden property here.**
          list.Items.Add(
          string.Format("{0} ({1}), {2}",
            webpart.Title, webpart.GetType().Name,
            zone.DisplayTitle));
        }
      }
      this.Controls.Add(list);
    }
```